# Prevent View from Being Dragged Off the Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to prevent views from being dragged past the edges of the screen. In other words, when the edge of the view comes to the edge of the screen, the view cannot be moved further in that direction.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touchInfo = [touches anyObject];

    if (touchInfo.view == self)
    {
        CGPoint touchStart = [touchInfo previousLocationInView:self];
        CGPoint touchEnd = [touchInfo locationInView:self];
        CGFloat xDifference = touchEnd.x - touchStart.x;
        CGFloat yDifference = touchEnd.y - touchStart.y;

        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + xDifference, self.center.y + yDifference);

        [self setCenter:newCenter];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect      bounds = self.bounds;
CGRect      limit = CGRectInset(self.superview.bounds, bounds.size.width / 2., bounds.size.height / 2.);
```

...

```
newCenter.x = fmaxf(limit.origin.x, fminf(limit.origin.x + limit.size.width, newCenter.x));
newCenter.y = fmaxf(limit.origin.y, fminf(limit.origin.y + limit.size.height, newCenter.y));
```

Answer (score 0):

add edge checks like this

```
CGRect superBounds = self.superView.bounds;

//check if this is past the right edge
if (newCenter.x + self.bounds.size.width/2 > superBounds.origin.x)
{
    newCenter.x = superBounds.size.width - self.bounds.size.width/2;
}

//Do the same thing for the top, bottom, and left edges
//...
```

Comment: How do I check for the top, bottom, and left edges?

Comment: You might want to read up on the UIKit coordinate system if you are not sure how to check for each of the edges.  The origin is the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CGRectContainsRect? Here's the documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsRect

```
if ( CGRectContainsRect(superViewBounds,subViewBounds) ){
//within the screen bounds
} else {
//_not_ within the screen bounds
}
```